# How to calculate the amount with conditional?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine

I have such documents in MongoDB:

```json
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"614e0f8fb2f4d8ea534b2ccb"
    },
    "userEmail":"abc@example.com",
    "customId":"abc1",
    "amountIn":10,
    "amountOut":0,
    "createdTimestamp":1632505743,
    "message":"",
    "status":"ERROR",
}
```

The `amountOut` field can be `0`, or a positive numeric value.
I need to calculate the sum of the `amountIn` and `amountOut` fields only if it is positive.
At the moment I am doing it like this:

```py
query = {
    'createdTimestamp': {'$gte': 1632430800},
    'createdTimestamp': {'$lte': 1632517200}
}
records = db.RecordModel.objects(__raw__=query).all()

total_amount = 0
for record in records:
    if record.amountOut > 0:
        total_amount += record.amountOut
    else:
        total_amount += record.amountIn
```

But this is very slow.
I know `mongoengine` has a `sum` method:

```py
total_amount = db.PaymentModel.objects(__raw__=query).sum('amountIn')
```

But I don't know how to use the condition for this method.
Maybe there are some other ways to calculate the amount with the condition I need faster?

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LqBwWVYHvpv) what you are looking for?

Comment: @ray yes, it looks like this is what I need, but how do I use this with ```mongoengine```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoengine's [aggregation api](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html?highlight=aggregation#mongodb-aggregation-api) which just allows you to execute aggregations normally.

Now you can use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z3edlft02bF) pipeline in code which utilizes `$cond`:

```
query = {
    'createdTimestamp': {'$gte': 1632430800, '$lte': 1632517200},
}
pipeline = [
    {"$match": query},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": None,
            "total_amount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$gt": [
                                "$amountOut",
                                0
                            ]
                        },
                        "$amountOut",
                        "$amountIn"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

records = db.RecordModel.objects().aggregate(pipeline)
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z3edlft02bF)